# Create a singleton for a Redux Store without attaching to window

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, singleton, redux, store

I'm looking for a way to import a created store in a node module, into other node modules. With the following few constraints I want to apply:

- It should be a singleton, every time I import it should (of course :) ) be the same store
- Avoid attaching to global 'window' object.
- Write in ES6, build with webpack.
- Modules import the store when a module requires it.

I have investigated a lot, but not come across a solution that matches the above.

So far I have this:

global_store:

```
import { setupStore } from './store';

const globalStore = setupStore({});

module.exports = globalStore;
```

Module A:

```
import globalStore from 'global_store';
import {
  ACTION_A
} from 'actions';

globalStore.dispatch({
  type: ACTION_A,
  payload: {
    item: 'item1',
  },
});
```

Module B:

```
import globalStore from 'global_store';
import {
  ACTION_B
} from 'actions';

globalStore.dispatch({
  type: ACTION_B,
  payload: {
    item: 'item2',
  },
});
```

The result is unfortunately that both modules create their own store. Is there something possible to use a shared store in a similar construction?

Comment: Your pattern seems correct. But I wouldn't suggest you to mix ES2015 modules and node module definitions (`import`/`export` vs `module.exports`). Maybe an issue with your webpack configuration, because this works -> http://www.webpackbin.com/VJQ78vqOG :)

Comment: @SebastianSebald Thanks! Not sure why I didn't get it right then, experimenting more now :)

Comment: @SebastianSebald Step closer to at least why this is happening. If I build all modules + store in the same build, I get the same store. However, if I build all the modules separately with Webpack (which is the case here), each gets it's own store.

Comment: @Sander found any solution for your issue?

Comment: No solution, due to the fact that Webpack creates it's own scope per build instance. Our environment uses different webpack builds leaving no other way than to bind to window until we have one build.